# How to find text in a file in bash and echo the output and add it to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to make a bash script that needs to find `http://0.0.0.0:3468/*`in a bunch of logs in `/opt/plex/*.log`, display it at the terminal for the user and at same time add it to a variable.

How can I do this?

Example : Print `http://0.0.0.0:3468/abc` to the terminal, and create a variable in the script called `TOKEN=abc`.

Comment: @Inian the url is always that. I also want to get everything after /*

Comment: Can you give some actual examples to come after `/*` and exactly say what you want to add it to a variable? By showing an example?

Comment: @Inian everything after /* is alphanumeric characters, I want to find that in the logs, print it to the user, and create variable TOKEN=/*

Comment: E.g. if you have `http://0.0.0.0:3468/abc`, you just want to see `abc`?

Comment: @Inian  want to print everything, including the url and what comes after /*, but make a variable only with the output after /*

Comment: Why do you want a variable? if there are multiple URLs present you need multiple variables to store your tokens right? You need an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on *supposed* requirements from the comments, you need something like below

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

token=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    token+=( "${line##*/}" )
done< <(awk '$0 ~ "http://0.0.0.0:3468/"' /opt/plex/*.log)
```

This will print all the matching lines containing the URL to the console. Instead of using a variable to store the token output you can use an array in `bash` to append the contents after `/` by using parameter expansion syntax of type `${word##*}` which removes the string up to the last occurrence of `/` and prints the remaining string. So once your script is completed, you can print the token list as just

```
printf '%s\n' "${token[@]}"
```

and access the individual token by looping over the array

```
for ((i=0; i< ${#token[@]}; i++ )); do 
    printf '%s\n' "${token[i]}"
done
```

(or) as just using array indices `${token[0]}`, `${token[1]}` etc.

---

If your requirement just boils down to get a single string value from the multiple set of files, just use `grep` or `Awk` as

```
token=$(awk -vFS=/ '$0 ~ "http://0.0.0.0:3468/"{print $NF}' /opt/plex_autoscan/*.log)
```

(or) with `GNU grep` as

```
token=$(grep -oP 'http://0.0.0.0:3468/\K.*) /opt/plex_autoscan/*.log
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67162/discussion-between-freedo-and-inian).